# pyspark Error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema

Tags: python, join, dataframe, pyspark

I have the below pyspark code to join two data frames. Everything looks simple but output is not coming with this erro. Unable to proceed further, can you please help to identify this fundamental issue here?

### Input

C.csv

```
100,2015-09-03,SG,7
200,2016-01-30,AT,9
300,2016-01-25,AU,8
400,2016-01-22,AU,7
```

U.csv

```
248,248,COUNTRY,SG,Singapore
66,66,COUNTRY,AT,Austria
65,65,COUNTRY,AU,Australia
```

### Output

```
100,Singapore
200,Austria
300,Australia
400,Australia
```

### Source

pyspark Code is :test.py

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark import SQLContext

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("HYBRID - READ CSV to HIVE ")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
C_rdd = sc.textFile("./hybrid/C.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))
R_rdd = sc.textFile("./hybrid/U.csv").map(lambda line: line.encode("ascii", "ignore").split(","))

C_df = C_rdd.toDF(['C_No','Op_Dt','Try_Cd','Lb'])
R_df = R_rdd.toDF(['C_Id','P_Id','CC_Cd','C_Nm','C_Ds'])

New = C_df.join(R_df, C_df.Try_Cd == R_df.C_Nm).select(['C_No','C_Ds'])
New.show()
```

### Result

```
Pyspark Error: $spark-submit  test.py
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 5 fields are required while 6 values are provided.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.EvaluatePython$.fromJava(python.scala:225)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$11.apply(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$11.apply(SQLContext.scala:933)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:149)
```

Can you please help what is the issue here?

Comment: Looks like error is thrown while doing `R_rdd.toDF` statement. The line "248,248,COUNTRY,SG,Singapore 66,66,COUNTRY,AT,Austria 65,65,COUNTRY,AU,Australia <> 100,Singapore 200,Austria 300,Australia 400,Australia` , is it continuous? it might be resulting in more than 5 columns when do you split on it.

Comment: Actually I was keeping all these rows in different lines but they come in this screen.file C.csv there are4 columns and file U.csv has 5 columns with data. The output I am expecting with two columns one from file-1 and another from file-2 by joining these two files data. But it is not working for some reason .. Can you please send if any sample working code for this case?

Comment: has this solution solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are using spark 2.x + then try this -

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StringType,IntegerType,StructField
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("HYBRID - READ CSV to HIVE ") \
    .getOrCreate()

cSchema = StructType([StructField("C_No", IntegerType()),
                     StructField("Op_Dt", StringType()),
                     StructField("Try_Cd", StringType()),
                     StructField("Lb", IntegerType())])

uSchema = StructType([StructField("C_Id", IntegerType()),
                     StructField("P_Id", IntegerType()),
                     StructField("CC_Cd", StringType()),
                     StructField("C_Nm", StringType()),
                     StructField("C_Ds", StringType())])

c_df  = spark.read.csv("c.csv",schema=cSchema)
u_df  = spark.read.csv("u.csv",schema=uSchema)

New = c_df.join(u_df, c_df.Try_Cd == u_df.C_Nm).select(c_df.C_No,u_df.C_Ds)
New.show()
```